# Can I cast phones display on laptop? my phones display not working

Tags: screen, moto-x, screencast

Mobile: Moto X2nd Generation 
OS: Android 6

My phones display not working, I am able to unlock it and touch is working.

Is there any application by which I can cast my phones display on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

[Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/download/) could solve your problem, it's available as a browser extension for Chrome or a standalone application for the three different operating systems: Windows, Mac and Linux.

> **Note:** USB Debugging should be enabled. If your USB debugging is not enabled, I suggest to look for another similar phone to simulate touches in order to activate USB Debugging.